# Book about half goddess who hunts with weapons that come out of her magic tattoos, bumps into a group of teenage hunters

Tags: story-identification, books

The plot of this book follows a female teenage hunter who on the night she decides to hunt in a popular nightclub, runs into a group of teenage hunters: a witch, a half succubi boy and a nephilim boy.

She has secrets she hides from them, one being her magic tattoos that she draws weapons out of; and the fact she is half goddess, daughter of Ares and has been exiled by her father after the deaths of her mother and little brother.

Comment: Do you know when you read this book? What do you mean by "hunter"? It's not typical to "hunt" in a "popular nighclub"...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking a good story-id question, to see if they help you remember any more details to [edit] into your question.  For example, do you remember what the cover of the book looked like?